# Make brew use an externally installed package as if it was brew-installed

Tags: macos, install, homebrew, package-management

I’m still using brew on macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra). I’m aware it has been no longer supported for some time now. I need rust and LLVM for some package support. How can I make this work with brew as if brew has installed these packages, make a tap?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787703

Comment: Try macports it supports High Sierra still (and as still suppoorts Tiger) it will support it for some time

Comment: @anki Any attempt at installing a late package with brew on my old system will result in a compile that will fail because of lack of dependencies, which is why I need brew to accept that I already have installed it myself, outside of brew.

Comment: @mmmmmm Does MacPorts support casks, and does it have author-signed and compiled binaries, or is it still all source and compiled at the user?

Comment: Macports has produce compiled binaries for the last 10 years - if the license allows it which is does for most licenses e.g. GPL MIT - so rust llvm emacs gcc are all compiled